# Comando for (CMD) para split em uma string

Tags: windows, cmd

Preciso pegar somente o número da versão do *Postgres* do comando `postgres -V`. Estou tentando fazer isso com o comando for, mas sem sucesso. Segue abaixo o comando original e a forma que estou tentando pegar o número 10:

Comando original: `postgres -V`

Saída: `postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.14` (Desejo pegar apenas o número 10 dessa saída, pois é o nome do diretório que vem antes do diretório bin, preciso disso para um script de backup que estou montando).

Tentativa de pegar apenas o número `10` com o comando `for`:

Entrada: `For /f "Tokens=1,3 delims=." %a in ('postgres -V') do (echo %a)`

Saída: `postgres (PostgreSQL) 10`

Entrada: `For /f "Tokens=2 delims=." %a in ('postgres -V') do (echo %a)`

Saída: `14`

Já tentei de várias formas, mas não consigo capturar apenas o número `10`. Alguém teria uma sugestão para eu conseguir fazer isso?

Comment: não tenho postgree instalado, mas o comando seria assim, faça um teste e se estiver ok eu ponho na resposta: `for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %a in ('postgres -V') do (echo %c)`

Comment: @RicardoPontual Não funcionou, saída é `10.14`.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do prompt de comando seria algo assim:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=. " %a in ('postgres -V') do echo %a
```

Para salvar a versão em uma variável chamada %Versao% dentro de um arquivo bat seria algo assim:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=. " %%a in ('postgres -V') do set Versao=%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>for /f "tokens=3 delims=). " %G in ('postgres -V')do @echo\%G
10
:: ou.. 

>for /f tokens^=3delims^=^).^  %G in ('postgres -V')do @echo\%G
10
```

---

- Para testar sem ter PostgreSQL instalado:

```
for /f delims^= %i in ('"echo/postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.14"')do @for /f tokens^=3delims^=^).^  %G in ('echo/%i')do @echo\%G

:: Ou.. 
 
for /f delims^= %i in ('"echo/postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.14"')do @for /f tokens^=3delims^=^).^  %G in ('echo/%i')do @echo\%G
```

---

Use multiplos `delimitadores`:  `) + . + Espaço`:

Apenas observe onde é necessário o uso de duplo espaço:

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=).Espaço"Espaço%G in (...
for /f tokens^=3^delims^=^).^EspaçoEspaço%G in (...
```